# How to display messages from jQuery Validate plugin inside of Tooltipster tooltips FOR SELECT INPUTS?

Tags: jquery, validation, tooltipster

I am using the Tooltipster plugin to display form errors generated by the jQuery Validate plugin, however i cant get it to display error's for select inputs

Comment: JSFiddle where i found original idea http://jsfiddle.net/2DUX2/

Answer (score 0):

https://gyazo.com/38ee0b71910510fa8a9d16b6c9663510

Solved was just a case of adding ,select after input[type="text"]

`// initialize tooltipster on text input elements
$('#details input[type="text"],select').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'custom',
    onlyOne: false,
    position: 'right'
});`